# Vector line inside Rectangle

Tags: c++, math, image-processing, opencv

what i got is a vector line (normalized vector vx,vy some point x0,y0, form fitLine OpenCv) and a rectangle defined by four points (clockwise p1,p2,p3,p4). now i need to know, if the line is going through the rectangle.. which means there need to be two points above (or left from) the line and two points below (or right from) the line. how can i archive this in c++?

Comment: how can you exclude that only one point is on a given side of the line and three ont the other hand side?

Answer (score 0):

This question looks like a homework ;)

First, you will need to discribe your line as an equation (1) such as Ax+By=C.  Any basic algebra book will tell you how to do that (or [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation)).

Then, you will need to find the similar equations for each edge of your rectangle.  Let's call those equations (2),(3),(4) and (5).

Then, you will need to find the intersection of (1) with each other equations.  Let's call thoses points a , b ,c and d.

Afterward, you will need to figure out for each intersection points if it stands between the appropriate vertexes.  If it's the case, they cross a rectangle edge!

If the your line cross at least one edge, you can say that your line cross your rectangle.

Here the challenge is to be able to deal with a line that is parralel to your rectangle or that is directly on one of a rectangle edge.  Do not be shy to make yourself a nice drawing to be sure of what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

The equation of your vector is

> y - y0 = (vy/vx) (x  - x0)

To tell whether point (x1,y1) is above, on or below the line, solve the line for x1 and compare y to y1.

```
 y > y1 - below
 y == y1 - on 
 y < y1 - above
```

So compare the your vector to each corner of the rectangle.